# Execute JQuery on specific img clicked within dynamic list of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am retrieving records from database and creating rows; in front of each row I put some icon (delete shape) to indicate the the user can delete the record,

```
<img id="imgDelete" name="<?php echo $Row['ID']; ?>" src='<?php echo $page_path; ?>/images/cross.png' border='0' alt='Delete' />
```

however in JQuery I can create function for img.click as:

```
$("imgDelete").click(function()
{
    alert("clicked");
});
```

and here I get the alert only one when I clicked on the first image within the rows, I think it is because the id of all images are same, I can change the id to be as

```
 id="imgDelete<?php echo $Row['ID']"
```

but then how can I make on.click event handler on array of image?

Comment: use class, IDs must be unique as you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This...

```
<img id="imgDelete<?php echo $Row['ID']" name="<?php echo $Row['ID']; ?>" src='<?php echo $page_path; ?>/images/cross.png' border='0' alt='Delete' />

$('img[id^="imgDelete"]').click( function(){
      var id = $(this).prop("name");
      alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you selects something in jquery using IDs
use

```
$("#imgDelete")
```

'#' mark. sample is..

```
$("#imgDelete").click(function()
{
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use class selector instead of using id selector.

I mean

```
$(".classname").click(function(){

});
```

instead of

```
$("#id").click(function(){

});
```

once you get the item then you can fetch its id and send to server for whatever you want like this:

```
$(".classname").click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
//send id to server
});
```

Comment: but here I will not be able to know which icon was clicked ?